# Passing values between expression engine templates

Tags: expressionengine, hidden-field

Any idea about How can I pass hidden values between 2 expression engine templates?

I don't want to use PHP code, is there any plugin or module?

Thanks

Comment: When you refer to 2 templates do you mean as embeds to deliver the same single page? Or between different site pages as a session or POST value?

Comment: between different site pages as a post value

Answer (score 2):

Highly recommend using [Session Variables](http://www.putyourlightson.net/session-variables-plugin/docs).

On your first page:

```
{exp:session_variables:set name="talking" value="nonsense"}
```

On your second page:

```
{exp:session_variables:get name="talking"}
```

Then you can always delete it afterwards:

```
{exp:session_variables:delete name="talking"}
```

If you want to deal with POST variables and set it on the first page via a form submission, then you can get it easily with [Mo' Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables):

```
{post:talking}
```

Comment: Kindly,Can you send me code which I write in first page and code I write in second page using Mo’ Variables plugin Thanks

Comment: You'd have to create a normal html form and submit it to the 2nd URL.

Comment: Ahmed - don't forget to mark the answer as the correct one - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking for is an add-on called [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) .  I think that would do exactly what you need!