# Passing url paramaters

Tags: url, expressionengine

Any idea about how can I send parameters in url query and get values of these parameters in next page

In first template I wrote this code

```
<a href ='r_rss/openOneNews?url={rss_link}'>{rss_title}</a>
```

Q:How can I get `url` parameter value in ExpressionEngine and use something like this in following page:

```
<iframe src = 'url' />
```

Thanks

Comment: Reminder: use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to escape `rss_link`

Comment: "in next page" you mean in the server response to `r_rss/openOneNews?url={rss_link}`? Please specify what language you use on the server then.

Comment: I use expression engine

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298910/passing-values-between-expression-engine-templates/19327066?noredirect=1#comment28658687_19327066) - you want to use [Mo' Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) to get the query string, which will then convert to a variable tag:

```
<iframe src = '{get:url}' />
```

Ahmed - please don't cross-post your question:

- https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14546/form-post-values
- https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14548/sending-paramters-in-url